# detect pandas column names if similiar match and process

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data that gets imported into a Pandas dataframe where that elements that are lists are being separated into new columns automatically.  My data was originally [.root](https://root.cern.ch/root-files) files and I am importing them in to Pandas with [Uproot](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Below is example data where the column physics[0] and physics[2](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) were originally elements of a list

```
data = {'physics[0]': [1,2,3], 'physics[1]': [4,5,6], 'yes': [7,8,9], 'no': [10,11,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)



   physics[0]  physics[1]  yes  no 
0           1           4    7  10  
1           2           5    8  11  
2           3           6    9  12
```

I am trying to come up with a technique to detect similar column names and recreate the elements as list.  Here is what I have so far:

```
lst = [col for col in df.columns if 'physics' in col]

df['physics']=df[lst].values.tolist()

    yes  no physics
0    7  10  [1, 4]
1    8  11  [2, 5]
2    9  12  [3, 6]
```

which works.  I won't always know before hand what the column names will be when this happens.  But I'd like to be able to detect if the names are similar automatically and perform the above list comprehension.

Comment: How do you define similar?

Comment: The column names being produced are physics[0] etc. so I’d like to match “physics” as the similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generalize your approach using regex:

```
import re
# create dictionary d of all groups of similar columns
multi_cols = filter(lambda x: re.search(r'\[[0-9]+\]$',x),df.columns)
d = {}
for c in multi_cols:
    k = re.sub(r'\[[0-9]+\]$', '' , str(c))
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = []
    d[k].append(c)

# the dictionary will be as following:
print(d)
# {'physics': ['physics[0]', 'physics[1]']}

# use dictionary d to combine all similar columns in each group
for k in d:
    df[k] = df[d[k]].values.tolist()
```

Comment: Genius!  Add 'import re'

Comment: Added `import re`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth checking out [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html). You can create l1 and l2 lists from your column headers, then utilize difflib's matching:

```
l1 = list(df.columns.values)
l2 = list(df.columns.values)

import difflib
difflib.get_close_matches(l1, l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume that any duplicate columns will always contain [0] at the end ?

what about something like this -

```
data = {'physics[0]': [1,2,3], 'physics[1]': [4,5,6], 'yes': [7,8,9], 'no': [10,11,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

duplicates = set([])
columns = df.columns
for c in columns:
    if c.endswith('[0]') and c.replace('[0]', '') not in duplicates:
        duplicates.add(c.replace('[0]', ''))

for d in duplicates:
    lst = [col for col in df.columns if d in col]
    df[d]=df[lst].values.tolist()
```

Comment: it seems that the new column names will contain [] at the end that iterates 0,1,2,3 and so on.